# Why does async await pattern in this console app caused a deadlock?

Tags: c#, async-await

Can anybody explain why this code simply hits a dead end after the WhenAll fires?

Main code:

```
class AsyncTests
{
    public async void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - starting whole process, calling await DoWork1()");
        await Task.WhenAll(DoWork1(), DoWork2());
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - finished awaiting DoWork1 and DoWork2");
    }

    public async Task DoWork1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - starting DoWork1");
        await DoNothing();
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - finished DoWork1");
    }

    public async Task DoWork2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - starting DoWork2");
        await DoNothing();
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - finished DoWork2");
    }

    public Task DoNothing() { return new Task(() => { /* do nothing */ }); }
}
```

The program control code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var x = new AsyncTests();
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - Main ... calling Start()");
        Task.Run(() => x.Start());
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - Main ... start is running");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The output:

```
Thread:1 - Main ... calling Start()
Thread:1 - Main ... start is running
Thread:4 - starting whole process, calling await DoWork1()
Thread:4 - starting DoWork1
Thread:4 - starting DoWork2
```

**UPDATE**

To make this a little clearer, let's change it so that  DoNothing actually calls Thread.Sleep(2000) and my objective is to run two thread sleeps simultaneously and want to use the async/await pattern to achieve this.

If I change "DoNothing" to be an async Task which performs a sleep, then I get told I need `await` operators in there.  Which means I'd need to write yet another `async` method to be awaited.  So what is the best way to end that chain of calls in terms of operators?

Can somebody show a best practise example of how to achieve the above?

Comment: What do you mean "hits a dead end"? What do you expect to see?

Comment: [Why aren't you using `Task.CompletedTask` instead of new'ing up a Task?](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html)

Comment: DoNothing is returning a Task object, but the Task object hasn't been started, so it won't complete (or fault), hence `await DoNothing();` is waiting forever...

Comment: `public Task DoNothing() { return Task.CompletedTask; }`

Comment: Side note: you are using an `sync void` (wrong) _and_ a `Task.Run()` (debatable). Stacking async patterns on top of each other is not a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately @HenkHolterman nobody seems able to describe what _is_ a good idea here.  Let's say we make the ``async void`` example a task.  Then we have to start the task in the calling code.  It doesn't change the execution.  Imagine that ``DoNothing`` actually calls ``Thread.Sleep(2000)`` and my objective is to run two thread sleeps simultaneously.  So I either start the Task returned by ``DoNothing()`` or I make it yet another async method - or even a regular synchronous method.  The calls to ``DoWork1`` and ``DoWork2``  will run synchronously, rather than asynchronously.

Comment: Well, somebody had [a good idea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Your question is too artificial, and it's not clear if you grasp the difference in async and parallel. What is Sleep() standing in for?

Comment: Sorry @HenkHolterman I guess you mean the question is not a real world example and is "synthesised"?  If so, no problem.  But I am examining here the behaviour of the async pattern and whether it can be used to achieve what I am suggesting.  I will update the question appropriately.

Comment: "of the async pattern" :  there is more than one. And mixing/confusing them causes all the problems.

Comment: Ok, I'll mark the answer from Lesiak as correct since this is the correct answer to the original question asked.   I am still unclear how to terminate a chain of async methods which return tasks for this particular example, but that is a separate question now.

Comment: @nlawalker see my own answer below for what I expected to see.  Dead end in this context basically means the code executing up to a point and then expected code not running.  My own answer below shows it coded and working as expected with the output I expected to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never start your task in DoNothing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

**Separating task creation and execution**

The Task class also provides constructors that initialize the task but that do not schedule it for execution. For performance reasons, the Task.Run or TaskFactory.StartNew method is the preferred mechanism for creating and scheduling computational tasks, but for scenarios where creation and scheduling must be separated, you can use the constructors and then call the Task.Start method to schedule the task for execution at a later time.

Comment: This is the right answer to the question asked technically, so marking as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a task to return, let the language do it for you.

```
public async Task DoNothing() { }
```

The above actually does nothing and will return a `Task` that is in its completed state and can be awaited.

The way you are currently doing it, the Task is created but it is never started or set to Completed, so awaiting it will lock up the program forever.

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the answers and comments already given, I wanted to show a code example working the way I intended in the test.  It shows the execution flow + for info, the managed thread Id of execution at specific times.

The main code:

```
class AsyncTests
{
    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} - Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - starting whole process, calling await DoWork1Async()");
        await Task.WhenAll(DoWork1Async(), DoWork2Async());
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} - Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - finished awaiting DoWork1Async and DoWork2Async");
    }

    public async Task DoWork1Async()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} - Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - starting DoWork1Async");
        await Sleep();
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} - Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - finished DoWork1Async");
    }

    public async Task DoWork2Async()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} - Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - starting DoWork2Async");
        await Sleep();
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} - Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - finished DoWork2Async");
    }        

    public async Task Sleep()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

The calling code (note that to make this run asynchronously I had to leave out the `await` operator which raises the warning `consider applying the 'await' operator` on the `StartAsync()` method call.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var x = new AsyncTests();
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - Main ... calling Start()");
    x.StartAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - Main ... start is running");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Finally, the output - which is as expected showing the code execution/control returning to the places expected for a truly asynchronous operation.  As expected two different pool threads were used to run the sleep.

```
10:43:36.515 - 1 - Main ... calling Start()
10:43:36.546 - Thread:1 - starting whole process, calling await DoWork1Async()
10:43:36.547 - Thread:1 - starting DoWork1Async
10:43:36.561 - Thread:1 - starting DoWork2Async
10:43:36.562 - 1 - Main ... start is running
10:43:38.581 - Thread:4 - finished DoWork2Async
10:43:38.582 - Thread:5 - finished DoWork1Async
10:43:38.582 - Thread:5 - finished awaiting DoWork1Async and DoWork2Async
```

Comment: Your logic now entirely depends on the Readkey().  Either use `async Task Main()` (C# >= 7.2) or use `x.StartAsync().Wait();`.

Comment: Not technically correct - the code will execute as expected but the ``Console.ReadKey()`` is just a way to interrupt execution.   I wanted it all to happen asynchronously, hence explicitly logging ``Main ... start is running`` from inside ``Main`` to illustrate the async code was running at the same time as this log entry and ``ReadKey()`` was running  in this case, so both ``.Wait()`` and ``async Task Main()`` would both defeat the point of the exercise ...